# How to make my jUnit tests more useful

Tags: java, model-view-controller, junit

I have the following model class (i'm using the MVC framework) and below it i have included my test class. I'm wanting to create a test class that's actualy useful and whilst my main methods are tested the test class doesn't feel all the useful (probably because i've created it after the model class). Would anyone have a suggestion on other parts of my model class i could target, or how to change my test class in such a way it's more useful.

```
public class GateInfoDatabase extends Observable {

    /**
     *  A constant: the number of aircraft gates at the airport.
     */
    public int maxGate = 3;
    private Gate[] gates = new Gate[maxGate];

    public GateInfoDatabase(){
        Gate gate0 = new Gate(0);
        Gate gate1 = new Gate(1);
        Gate gate2 = new Gate(2);

        gates[0] = gate0;
        gates[1] = gate1;
        gates[2] = gate2;
    }

    /**
     * Obtain and return the status of the given gate identified by the gateNumber parameter.
     * @return 
     */
    public Gate getGate(int gateNumber){
        Gate result = gates[gateNumber];
        return result;
    }
    /**
     * Obtain and return the status of the given gate identified by the gateNumber parameter.
     * @return 
     */
    public Gate getGateByMCode(int mCode){
        Gate result = null;
        for(int i = 0; i < gates.length; i++) {
            if(mCode == gates[i].getmCode()) {
                result = gates[i];
                System.out.print(result);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    /**
     * Obtain and return the status of the given gate identified by the gateNumber parameter.
     * @return 
     */
    public int getStatus(int gateNumber){

        return gates[gateNumber].getStatus();
    }
    /**
     * Obtain and return the status of the given gate identified by the gateNumber parameter.
     * @return 
     */
    public int getStatusByMCode(int mCode){
        int nStatus = ManagementRecord.FREE;
        Gate result = getGateByMCode(mCode);
        if(result!=null) {
            nStatus = result.getStatus();
        }
        return nStatus;
    }
    /**
     * Returns an array containing the status of all gates.
     * For data collection by the GOC.
     */
    public int[] getStatuses(){

        int[] statuses = new int[maxGate];

        for(int i = 0; i < maxGate; i++){

            statuses[i] = gates[i].getStatus();
        }
        return statuses;
    }

    /**
     * Forward a status change request to the given gate identified by the gateNumber parameter. Called to allocate a free gate to the aircraft identified by mCode.
     */
    public void allocate(int gateNumber, int mCode){

        gates[gateNumber].allocate(mCode);
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(); 

    }

    /**
     * Forward a status change request to the given gate identified by the gateNumber parameter. Called to indicate that the expected aircraft has arrived at the gate.
     */
    public void docked(int gateNumber){
        gates[gateNumber].docked();
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(); 
    }

    /**
     * Forward a status change request to the given gate identified by the gateNumber parameter. Called to indicate that the aircraft has departed and that the gate is now free.
     */
    public void departed(int gateNumber){
        gates[gateNumber].departed();
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(); 
    }

    public int getmCode(int gateNumber){

        return gates[gateNumber].getmCode();
    }

}
```

Test class

```
public class GateTest {


    GateInfoDatabase model = new GateInfoDatabase();
    ManagementRecord mrc= new ManagementRecord();

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        model = new GateInfoDatabase();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        model = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreate() {
        assertNotNull("Model not created properly", model);
        assertEquals("Initial gate setup is wrong", model.maxGate, model.getStatuses().length);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetGate() {
        Gate gate = model.getGate(0);
        assertNotNull("Gate should not be null", gate);
        assertEquals("Should be return right gate", new Gate(0).getStatus(), gate.getStatus());
        assertEquals("Should be return right gate", new Gate(0).getGateNumber(), gate.getmCode());
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetGateByMCode() {
        Gate gate = model.getGateByMCode(0);
        assertNotNull("Gate should not be null", gate);
        assertEquals("Should be return right gate", new Gate(0).getStatus(), gate.getStatus());
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetStatuses() {
        int[] statuses = model.getStatuses();
        assertNotNull("Gate should not be null", statuses);
        assertEquals("Should be equal number of gate", 3, statuses.length);
        assertEquals("Should be return right gate", 0, statuses[0]);
    }
    @Test
    public void testAllocate() {
        model.allocate(1,2);
        Gate gate = model.getGateByMCode(2);
        assertNotNull("Gate should not be null", gate);
        assertEquals("Should be equal number of gate", 1, gate.getGateNumber());
    }

    @Test
    public void testDocked() {
        model.docked(1);
        Gate gate = model.getGate(1);
        assertNotNull("Gate should not be null", gate);
        assertEquals("Should be right status after departure", 2, gate.getStatus());
    }

    @Test
    public void testDeparted() {
        model.docked(1);
        model.departed(1);
        Gate gate = model.getGate(1);
        assertNotNull("Gate should not be null", gate);
        assertEquals("Should be right status after departure", 0, gate.getStatus());
    }





}
```

Comment: I’d start by getting rid of magic numbers.  `assertEquals("...", 2, gate.getStatus());`???  What does 2 mean?  If you’ve got named `int` constants defined (eg, `Management.FREE`), use them.  Better, use `enum` constants.

Comment: the 2 corresponds to a specific status in the gate class i have, thanks for the advice